# Adding a Angular 1.8 component in a React page

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

I'm migrating an Angular 1.8 page into React 17. I did most of it but I have this really big Angular component that it will take a really long time to migrate to React.
Can I add this Angular 1.8 component to the React 17 page?

I have add React 17 components into an Angular 1.8 page. But is it possible the other way around?

I research a little bit, I found this article: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-and-react-together-with-ivy-5c77d1f48204 , but it's a more advanced Angular.

Anyone done this? Maybe a work around solution?

Comment: That tutorial is using Angular 8 and you are using 1.8.  A simple idea is to show an iframe with that 1.8 component and related ceremony.

Comment: @SanishJoseph Can I communicate with the component in the iframe?

Comment: You will have only one option that is using all those params you need to pass in URL. If that's not feasible, you need to find a common place where both React and Angular can fetch data eg: A database with an API that both react and angular can communicate. I can't think of any easy ideas.